# How to access specific table shown in inspect using Python and BeautifulSoup for web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am working on web scraping using Python and BeautifulSoup. My purpose is to pull members data from https://thehia.org/directory?&tab=1. There are around 1685 records.

When I view the page source on my Chrome, I cannot find the table. Seems it dynamically pulls the data. But when I use the inspect option of Chrome, I can find the "membersTable" table in the div that I need.

[image]

How can I use BeautifulSoup to access that membersTable that I can access in the inspect.

Answer (score 1):

You can mimic the POST request the page makes for content then use hjson to handle unquoted keys in string pulled out of response

```
import requests, hjson
import pandas as pd

data = {'formId': '3721260'}
r = requests.post('https://thehia.org/Sys/MemberDirectory/LoadMembers', data=data)
data = hjson.loads(r.text.replace('while(1); ',''))
total = data['TotalCount']
structure = data['JsonStructure']
members = hjson.loads(structure)
df = pd.DataFrame([[member[k][0]['v'] for k in member.keys()] for member in members['members'][0]]
            ,columns = ['Organisation', 'City', 'State','Country'])
print(df)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
   import requests
   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


    url = "https://thehia.org/directory?&tab=1"
    response = requests.get(url)
    html = response.content

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class': 'membersTable'})

    row_list = []
    for row in table.findAll('tr',{'class':['normal']}):
        data= []
        for cell in row.findAll('td'):
            data.append(cell.text)
        row_list.append(data)

    print(row_list)
```

Comment: Thank your for the code but this doesn't work because the table does not exists in html. As shown in the image above, I can manually inspect by scrolling down to find the membersTable, but I don't know how I can accomplish this by using Python.